# After reboot, 20.04.4LTS left side app icons missing and show applications 9 dot doesn't do any thing when clicked on

Tags: ubuntu-dock

20/04.4LTS, file maint was a poor choice of words,since all the application icons were missing, just needed to open web browser,  I Go to dash & type f, I open fire fox,the left side icons return,shortly after FF opens.
Using full disk encryption,
I am running two monitors 1,Acer 24 inch on DVI and Emerson Tv on HDMI/
Gigabyte mother bd.GA-78'LMT, 8 gig ram AND FX 6350,6 core, AMD proc Video card Cedar.  Ubuntu 20.04.4LTS, 64 bit Gnome 3.36.8 Wayland.

Comment: You need a lot more info if you expect any help. First what version of Ubuntu? What do you mean by file maintenance? What steps are you doing? The title does not make a lot of sense. What does 9 dot does not work mean? Please edit your question.

Comment: Thanks David, hopefully with added info, i donut appears as a raw noob.